# Pandas time series tracking of sold unit sizes

Tags: pandas, numpy

I've got a tshirt sales csv indexed by date i.e.

```
            Sold    Size
Date        
2017-02-22  640000  S
2017-10-21  190000  L
2017-12-21  190000  XS
2017-06-25  181000  XXL
```

I need to create a time series tracking the sales of each size. I.e. if I give date range of 2017-02 to 2017-11 I need to display how much each tshirt SIZE has sold.

Comment: How much detail do you need? Do you know how to create the Datetime index? Is getting the data into the DataFrame solved and you are you just stuck on how to aggregate the sales per tshirt size? Are you familiar with pandas `groupby` method which you would chain a function after such as `sum()`?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
df[(df["Date"] >= 2017-02-01) & (df["Date"] <= 2017-11-30)].groupby("Size")["Sold"].sum()
```